# AnyRef equivalent for an AnyVal type

Tags: scala, types

Given a type `T`, is there an idiomatic Scala way to describe the `AnyRef` equivalent  of `T` (let's call it `ARE[T]`). For example,

- `ARE[T <: AnyRef]` is `T`
- `ARE[T <: AnyVal]` is the `java.lang.*` equivalent of `T` when one exists or a compilation error when it does not

The purpose of the question is to allow implementing many methods such as:

```
def foo[A](...): ARE[A]
```

while avoiding the naive `def foo[A <: AnyRef](...): A` + overloading for Boolean, Byte, Char, Double, Float, Int, Long and Short.

Comment: What would you like to gain from constrainting on `AnyVal`? Avoid boxing?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the goal is not to avoid boxing: by definition `AnyRef`-equivalent types are heap-allocated. The goal is to smoothly use non-standard collections that require `T <: AnyRef`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking if there is an `ARE[A]` equivalent exposed by the Scala language to allow you to use it instead of constraining `T` everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to implement a type computation like this is to create a typeclass:

```
sealed trait Box[T] {
  type Out
  def apply(t: T): Out
}

object Box {
  type Aux[T, ARE] = Box[T] { type Out = ARE }

  def make[T, ARE](f: T => ARE): Box.Aux[T, ARE] = new Box[T] {
    type Out = ARE
    def apply(t: T) = f(t)
  }

  implicit val int: Box.Aux[Int, java.lang.Integer] = make(Int.box)
  implicit val long: Box.Aux[Long, java.lang.Long] = make(Long.box)
  implicit val short: Box.Aux[Short, java.lang.Short] = make(Short.box)
  implicit val byte: Box.Aux[Byte, java.lang.Byte] = make(Byte.box)
  implicit val char: Box.Aux[Char, java.lang.Character] = make(Char.box)
  implicit val float: Box.Aux[Float, java.lang.Float] = make(Float.box)
  implicit val double: Box.Aux[Double, java.lang.Double] = make(Double.box)
  implicit val boolean: Box.Aux[Boolean, java.lang.Boolean] = make(Boolean.box)
  implicit val unit: Box.Aux[Unit, scala.runtime.BoxedUnit] = make(Unit.box)
  implicit def anyRef[T <: AnyRef]: Box.Aux[T, T] = make(identity)

  def box[T](t: T)(implicit are: Box[T]): are.Out = are(t)
}
```

This can be used like any other typeclass. For example, you can compute the type `ARE` with the help of `Box.Aux` in your own functions:

```
def box2[T, ARE](t: T)(implicit box: Box.Aux[T, ARE]): ARE = box(t)
```

Scala accepts the output of `Box.box` when `AnyRef` is expected:

```
scala> def foo[T <: AnyRef](anyRef: T): T = anyRef
foo: [T <: AnyRef](anyRef: T)T

scala> foo(10)
<console>:13: error: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method foo's type parameter bounds [T <: AnyRef]
       foo(10)
       ^
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(10)
 required: T
       foo(10)
           ^

scala> foo(Box.box(10))
res1: Box.int.Out = 10
```

And Scala also knows the exact `ARE` type returned from `Box.box`:

```
scala> def bar[T](t: T)(implicit ev: T =:= java.lang.Integer) = ev
bar: [T](t: T)(implicit ev: =:=[T,Integer])=:=[T,Integer]

scala> bar(10)
<console>:13: error: Cannot prove that Int =:= Integer.
       bar(10)
          ^

scala> bar(Box.box(10))
res2: =:=[Box.int.Out,Integer] = <function1>
```